# how to select no of records based on count using Hive

Tags: hive

I have the tabel with below structure

```
acct_no   cid
12344      33
34555      32
21111      33
12222      33
11112      21
```

now i need all the details for the CID which are less than 2.
I have tried below however iam facing some issues.

```
SELECT * FROM bcamxn1 GROUP BY cid HAVING COUNT(cid<10);
```

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 1:42 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'count'

Comment: The question is unclear, I think the best way is to provide an example of the expected result for a small set of data. 
You say you want the CID are less than 2 but then in your example you have `cid<10`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in query:

```
SELECT * FROM bcamxn1 GROUP BY cid HAVING COUNT(cid)<10;
```

As input for the COUNT is not recognized. The other way to select all CID's below some level is:

```
SLECT * FROM bcamxn1 WHERE cid<10 GROUP BY cid;
```